# Fast days for a person with an eating disorder

Tags: halacha, medicine, fast-days, eating, pikuachnefesh-danger-life

Does anyone know of a posek who has written about people with eating disorders (I know there are many types of eating disorders) or people who have recovered from an eating disorder regarding whether or not they should fast on fast-days? I would like to find some material addressing this question.

I ask because being mandated to not eat for an entire day can be physically/emotionally/psychologically dangerous or harmful to people who are sick with an eating disorder.

Comment: "physically/emotionally/psychologically dangerous or harmful" It would be Pikuach Nefesh?? Sounds unlikely, but IANAP

Comment: @DoubleAA As I noted in the question, there are many types of eating disorders and differing levels of severity. There are definitely cases where a person's life can be put at risk (or parts of their bodies, like specific organs).

Comment: Ill person aren't in duty to fast at all. Psychiatric disorders when not in full remission are generally regarded as illnesses. In addition several of them need to be treated by drugs which can generate loss of blood pressure in case of tsom, fast can cause anxiety. Anyway each case needs a question to the patient caregiver and the rav

Comment: Each case needs the input of a qualified rav. I'm pretty sure eating disorders count as illness; I'll try to post an answer if/when I find a source for you